# ASP.NET Core MVC Health Check failing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package, swisscomdev

I try to run a ASP.NET Core MVC Web application on the Swisscom Appcloud. But when I start the Application I get following Error-Message in the Console:

```
2017-01-24 14:29:53 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
```

Its looks like the Appcloud cannot check the Health of my Application. Do I need to install a Nuget-Package or something else to get this up and running?

Thanks for your effort

Comment: No expert here, but if indeed it uses Cloud Foundry then maybe this page can provide some insight: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

Comment: @PeterB this was not helpful but thaks for your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gsmachado has already mentioned, you must listen to a specific port.

The .NET Core buildpack configures the app web server automatically so you don’t have to handle this yourself. But you have to prepare your app in a way that allows the buildpack to deliver this information via the command line to your app.

The buildpack will start your app with the following command:

`$ dotnet run --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:${PORT}`

Therefore you have to add the command line as a configuration provider and then add the UseConfiguration extension to pass the configuration to the WebHostBuilder

e.g.:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddCommandLine(args)
.Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, Cloud Foundry makes a health check by trying to connect to the port which the application is exposing.

If your application is not exposing ANY port (e.g., it's not a web service with APIs and so on), then you should add the `health-check-type` attribute to `none`, as described [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#health-check-type).

If after that you still get errors, then I suggest you to find where your application is listening to a given port. In Cloud Foundry you must listen to `$PORT`, which is a environment variable. You can check an example of that [here](http://harrewijnen.net/my-first-asp-net-core-app-on-cloud-foundry/).